Crash when opening a window leveraging NSHostingView wrapper in SwiftUI on MacOS (Sonoma)
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
#if os(macOS)
        VStack {
            Button("Open Window 2") {
                Window2().openInWindow(title: "Window 2", sender: self)
            }
            .contextMenu {
                Button("window1menuItem") {
                    // Action for window1menuItem
                }
            }
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
#endif
    }
}

struct Window2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is Window 2")
            .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
            .contextMenu {
                Button("window2menuItem") {
                    // Action for window2menuItem
                }
            }
    }

    func openInWindow(title: String, sender: Any?) {
#if os(macOS)
        let window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 280, height: 200),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName(title)
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: self)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(sender)
#endif
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

crashes like so

when closing window2 with the red dot in the top left corner.
closing window1 does not crash the app. Closing window2 after closing window1 does crash the app just the same as did closing window2 with window1 open.
Questions:

Is there anything obviously wrong with my sample app
Is SwiftUI best avoided for production grade apps targeting MacOS & iPadOS yet?
Thanks. Sonoma 14.4.1 Xcode 15.3


Separate openInWindow use something like NSHostingView(rootView: Window2()). But SwiftUI has “openWindow” Environment property too. self is getting killed instantly.

You're right. openWindow env prop template https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-open-a-new-window saved the day. Feel free to write it up as an answer for upvoting.

Separate openInWindow use something like NSHostingView(rootView: Window2()).
SwiftUI has openWindow Environment property too.
In your code self is getting killed instantly.
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-open-a-new-window

making openInWindow static and moving Window2() inside NSHostingView(rootView: instead of leaving is a member function and passing self changes nothing. thusly mind if I neuter the question a bit leaving just the openWindow Environment property?
